Remove id in url in .net core
How do I omit the Id from the URL? Change from this URL:
https://localhost:7002/Product/109

to this instead ====>
https://localhost:7002/Product/productName

My controller is:
    [Route("/Product/{id}")]
    public IActionResult ShowProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = _productRipository.GetProductById(id);
        ViewBag.ProductGalleries = product.Product_Galleries
                                          .Select(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID).ToList();
        ViewBag.ProductFeatures = product.Product_Features
                                         .Select(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID).ToList();
        ViewBag.ProductVideos = product.Product_Videos
                                       .Select(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID).ToList();
        ViewBag.ProductFiles = product.Product_Files
                                      .Select(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID).ToList();

        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(product);
    }


Create an API action (method) with parameter: productName with string type.

Do you want two paths? One with id and one with name?

No just with name

It looks like you'd rather identify the product on the route based on the product name, rather than the ID. I'd do something similar to:
[Route("/Product/{productName}")]
public IActionResult ShowProduct(string productName)
{
    Product? product = _productRepository.FindProductByName(productName);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        //whatever other operations you need 
        return View(product);    
    }
}


[Route("/Product")]
public IActionResult ShowProduct(int id)
{
            var id = User?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
    var product = _productRipository.GetProductById(id);
    ViewBag.ProductGalleries=product.Product_Galleries.Select(p=>p.ProductID==product.ProductID).ToList();
    ViewBag.ProductFeatures = product.Product_Features.Select(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID).ToList();
    ViewBag.ProductVideos = product.Product_Videos.Select(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID).ToList();
    ViewBag.ProductFiles = product.Product_Files.Select(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID).ToList();

    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(product);
}

